# Word Macro Shuts Down exactly half way through Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

My first challenge was to automate underlining headers in a word doc. This code worked:

```
Sub Underline_Header()

Dim numOfParagraphs As Integer
numOfParagraphs = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("NUMBER OF PARAGRAPHS")
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
For x1 = 1 To numOfParagraphs

Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select

char_count = Len(Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range)

If char_count < 50 Then
Selection.Font.Underline = True
End If

Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1

Next x1


End Sub
```

But it turns out if the doc is 20 pages, the macro stops at page 10. If 10, stops at 5. 4, then stops at page 2.

I have tried altering the code at `Unit:=wdStory` to `Unit:=wdDocument` but that was not the solution. I also tried adding `Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory` to the code but I get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify it to something like

```
Sub Underline_Headers()
    Dim p As Paragraph
    For Each p in ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If Len(p.Range.Text) < 50 Then
            p.Range.Font.Underline = True
        End If
    Next p
End Sub
```